# Does OpenCL 1.0 support parallel read or write from file?

Tags: opencl, gpu

I am using JOCL to write a parallel program. The OpenCL version supported by my GPU is 1.0. It allows to read arrays into global memory and process it in parallel. 
I have an excel file from which the data must be read into those arrays. Is it possible to read data into those arrays parallely? Is there any tutorial using which I could understand these concepts clearly?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid, there is no direct way of reading files from OpenCL into a kernel program. You have to choose a file operation library to import the data into the host memory. This strongly depends on you application language (mostly C++ or Java).

After that, the usual OpenCL memory transactions can take place.
Also be aware, that operations on a single file are usually hard to parallelize. Most of the executed program code is much more faster than the file operation code, especially if using OpenCL.

You can find a lot of introductional tutorial on OpenCL online. Maybe you could provide some information about your further data processings.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I use Java for executing the serial code which includes accessing the excel file. I now realized that it would be a bad idea to convert it to OpenCL, because I use a single file.
The kernel function which I have implemented performs Laplace distribution on the data.

Comment: In general it is not a bad idea to use OpenCL. But there is a strong demand for a intermediate data structure, that loads the excel data from a file and converts it into OpenCL data structures like arrays. Of course it depends on the size of the data and the functional dependencies of the application, if an OpenCL solution could be faster than a non-accelerated, CPU-based implementation.